# Inserting datetime into MySQL table past 24 hour mark

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm inserting data into a table which include datetimes as follows:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2014-10-06 24:04:05','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

For all records with a time starting with "24" (as above), it's appearing as "NULL" in my table because it's not recognized.

How can I change the 24's into 00's when I'm inserting into my table? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Are you inserting the rows into MySQL using PHP? why not check for 24hour using PHP and then convert it to `00`?

Comment: Hi, I'm doing it straight in MySQL with script:  `INSERT INTO`

Comment: I think you're solving the wrong end of the problem here.  That's not a valid time.  You need to find where it's coming from and *fix that*.

Comment: Yes, fair point and one I'll look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE`-function in MySQL

```
STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('2014-10-06 24:04:05',' 24:',' 00:'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

This way replace matches only the hour part and if hour is not 24 simply nothing will be changed.

Comment: Thanks mäksä, that works.   On reflection, I can also open my script in a text editor and do a Replace All with "24:" and "00:". Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Remember to put white space before 24: because otherwise 01:01:24 will be converted to 01:01:00

Answer (score 0):

For date type column. Use type 'date' which is in 'YYYY-mm-dd h:i:s' format.

So, `echo $CurrentDateTime1=date('Y-m-d G:i:s'); => 2015-08-26 20:21:22`

or, `echo $CurrentDateTime2=date('d-m-Y G:i:s'); => 26-08-2015 20:21:22`

So, $CurrentDateTime2 is not in Y-m-d format. You need to change this format.
So, Change it in this way.

```
echo $CurrentDateTime3=date('Y-m-d G:i:s',strtotime($CurrentDateTime2)) 
=>2015-08-26 20:21:22
```

Now, insert '$CurrentDateTime3' in table.